# Parsing bracketed string (integers) in python

Tags: string, parsing, tree

I have a genuine problem. I need to parse a string input example: (((10)40((25)30(35)))50((70(80(40)))60))

Yes this is code for a tree. I need to do some checks to find specific
nodes but for now i just wonna build the directory or list for this tree.
then i can manage the checks on my own. i think.

and from this get a workable output.
best case scenario would be something like a directory like so:
{(0:50),(1:40,60)...}

altho even simply getting the right integers to append to some list
is workable with.

I have tried for hours to code something alike but i always get stuck.
My best bet was this code :
def parsing_input(string_brackets):

```
def parsing_input(string_brackets):

stack=[]
counter = -1
for character in string_brackets:
    if character == '(':
        counter += 1
        stack.append('')
    elif character==')':
        counter -= 1
    else:
        stack[counter] += character
return stack
```

with output:

['50', '4060', '103070', '253580', '40', '', '', '', '', '']

but this doesnt work, my integers could be different sizes so i cant just separate them. also i dont like those empty strings. they might slow down the
code. I honestly have been trying for hours.

EDIT: forgot to say that i am not allowed to use external libraries. I am aware that some libraries can do this easily but i cannot use them.

Answer (score 0):

With code in it's current form, you should be able to add separation by appending a comma before you subtract.  As far as deleting empty buckets, you can do that on a second run through your stack.  Also, on the second run, you could build the directory that you wanted as a second variable.

```
def parsing_input(string_brackets):

stack=[]
counter = -1
for character in string_brackets:
    if character == '(':
        counter += 1
        stack.append('')
    elif character==')':
        if len(stack[counter]) > 0 and stack[counter][-1:] != ',':
            stack[counter] += ','
        counter -= 1
    else:
        stack[counter] += character
return stack
```

Comment: i tried ur code and i managed to create a directory with the depths, however ijust realized that for my checks i need to know the structure of the tree ie. the parent of each of the children. with my current input sequence i cannot know what comes where. i need a different input sequence code